# Xamarin iOS 7: Native linking failed

Tags: ios, debugging, build, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am getting a build error while trying to build/debug my app.. This just happened after upgrading Xamarin to iOS7.

I can figure how to fix this.

Here's my console output:

```
Building: nytLectio (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)
Performing main compilation...
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.2/bin/mcs /noconfig "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll" -nostdlib "/out:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Data.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/mbprogresshud-0.5.2/lib/ios/MBProgressHUD.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/irate-1.7.2/lib/ios/MTiRate.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/GoogleAnalytics.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/mbalertview-1.0/lib/ios/AlertView.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/xamarin.social-1.1/lib/ios/Xamarin.Auth.iOS.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/xamarin.social-1.1/lib/ios/Xamarin.Social.iOS.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/parse-1.2.7/lib/ios/Parse.iOS.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/json.net-4.5.11/lib/ios/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/xamarin.mobile-0.6.3/lib/ios/Xamarin.Mobile.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.Controls.iOS.ProgressBar.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.Controls.iOS.Switch.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.Utils.iOS.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.iOS.dll" "/r:/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/googleadmob-6.5.0/lib/ios/GoogleAdMobAds.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG;__MOBILE__;__IOS__"  /t:exe "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/Main.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioSkemaViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioSkemaViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/reachability.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioStartsideViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioStartsideViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioFraViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioFraViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioOpgaveViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioOpgaveViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioBeskedViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioBeskedViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioSkoleViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytLectioSkoleViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytlectioSettViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytlectioSettViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/InAppPurchaseManager.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/VerificationController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/CustomPaymentObserver.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/SKProductExtension.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/proManager.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/viewExtensions.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nyforsideViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nyforsideViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytlectioErrorViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/nytlectioErrorViewController.designer.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/ytLectioErrorViewController.cs" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/ytLectioErrorViewController.designer.cs" 
Compilation succeeded - 5 warning(s)

/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/InAppPurchaseManager.cs(90,34): warning CS0618: `MonoTouch.StoreKit.SKPayment.PaymentWithProduct(string)' is obsolete: `Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use PaymentWithProduct(SKProduct) after fetching the list of available products from SKProductRequest'
/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/VerificationController.cs(61,53): warning CS0618: `MonoTouch.StoreKit.SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt' is obsolete: `Deprecated in iOS7'
/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/VerificationController.cs(108,25): warning CS0618: `MonoTouch.StoreKit.SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt' is obsolete: `Deprecated in iOS7'
/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/VerificationController.cs(109,25): warning CS0618: `MonoTouch.StoreKit.SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt' is obsolete: `Deprecated in iOS7'
/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/VerificationController.cs(115,51): warning CS0618: `MonoTouch.StoreKit.SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt' is obsolete: `Deprecated in iOS7'



Compiling Asset Catalogs
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --platform iphonesimulator --minimum-deployment-target "7.0" --compile "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/Resources/Images.xcassets"
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app/Assets.car


Copying content files
Copying '/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/Resources/Icon-60@2x.png' to '/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app/Icon-60@2x.png'

Optimizing png for iOS
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/Resources/Icon-60@2x.png" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app/Icon-60@2x.png"
Copying '/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/Resources/Icon-Small-40@2x.png' to '/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app/Icon-Small-40@2x.png'

Optimizing png for iOS
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/Resources/Icon-Small-40@2x.png" "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app/Icon-Small-40@2x.png"
Build complete -- 0 errors, 5 warnings

Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --cache "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache" --nomanifest --nosign -sim "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Data.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/mbprogresshud-0.5.2/lib/ios/MBProgressHUD.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/irate-1.7.2/lib/ios/MTiRate.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/GoogleAnalytics.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/mbalertview-1.0/lib/ios/AlertView.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/xamarin.social-1.1/lib/ios/Xamarin.Auth.iOS.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/xamarin.social-1.1/lib/ios/Xamarin.Social.iOS.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/parse-1.2.7/lib/ios/Parse.iOS.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/json.net-4.5.11/lib/ios/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/xamarin.mobile-0.6.3/lib/ios/Xamarin.Mobile.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.Controls.iOS.ProgressBar.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.Controls.iOS.Switch.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.Utils.iOS.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/fitpulsetheme-1.0/lib/ios/FitpulseTheme.iOS.dll" -r "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/Components/googleadmob-6.5.0/lib/ios/GoogleAdMobAds.dll" -debug -nolink -sdk "7.0" -targetver "7.0" --abi=i386 "/Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.exe"
Xamarin.iOS 6.9.7 Indie Edition using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -lz -lsqlite3 -Wl,-pie  -gdwarf-2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -Qunused-arguments -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.i386.o -force_load /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libMBProgressHUD.a -force_load /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libMBAlertView.a -force_load /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAdMobAds.a -force_load /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libAdmobExporter.a -force_load /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libiRate.a -force_load /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAnalytics.a -o /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/nytLectio.app/nytLectio -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Accounts -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion -framework GameKit -framework GLKit -framework iAd -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenGLES -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework Twitter -framework UIKit -framework PassKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreImage -framework ImageIO -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -framework ExternalAccessory -framework QuickLook -weak_framework SpriteKit -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework MultipeerConnectivity -weak_framework GameController -weak_framework MediaAccessibility -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework AdSupport -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_get_locale_country_code -u _monotouch_log -u _monotouch_start_wwan -u _monotouch_timezone_get_data -u _monotouch_timezone_get_names -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a
ld: in /Users/Emil/Projects/nytLectio/nytLectio/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o), too many compact unwind infos in function anon for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

--------------------- Færdig ---------------------

Build: 1 error, 5 warnings
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was reported elsewhere ([XCode 5 GM linker error: too many compact unwind infos in function anon for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731667/xcode-5-gm-linker-error-too-many-compact-unwind-infos-in-function-anon-for-arch) and https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=338)

Apparently, this only happens on the simulator, and your app should work just fine in debug mode on your device.

Another way to workaround this is to set the target to iOS 6.1